# How do I use reflection to invoke a private method with array of String as parameter

Tags: java, reflection

I try to call a private method with the following code. but I get an IllegalArgumentException.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

The code is :

```
Method method = MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", String[].class);
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(myClassInstance, new String[] { "a", "b" });
```

The signature of the method being called is :

```
private void myMethod(String[] args)
```

I tried the same example but with a method taking a String as parameter and it worked fine.

Many thanks

Comment: I don't have a compiler handy to test, but I suspect the `String[]` is being passed as the entire `Object...` argument instead of as a single element. Try `method.invoke(myClassInstance, new Object[] { new String[] { "a", "b" } });`

Comment: That worked. do you have an explanation ?

Comment: It's just how Java works, you can call a varargs function `foo(Object... x)` as either `foo(a, b, c)` or `foo(new Object[] { a, b, c})`. The compiler interprets your code as the latter one. To force it to interpret it as the former, you need to manually add the boilerplate.

Comment: In `invoke(Object obj, Object... args)` `args` has to *hold* arguments, not *be* argument. When you pass `new String[] { "a", "b" }` it is treated as representation of `args` (we can use Object[] to hold String[]). But since that array *holds* 2 arguments: `a` and `b` you are getting exception. So either explicitly wrap your array in Object[] (so invoke would be able to use `args[0]` to get your array), or cast it to Object like `(Object)new String[] { "a", "b" }` to let varargs treat it as single argument which will need to be wrapped in varargs array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A String array is seen by the compiler as a varargs. Then your invoke method is seeing 2 String passed as parameters instead of a String array.